# Mongoose Query update, $pull, multi

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

A short and simple question.

Would someone be kind enough to tell me what the Mongoose equivalent of this Mongo query would be...

```
db.users.update({ groups: "d" },{ $pull: { groups: "d" } },{ multi: true })
```

Just getting my head around more basic mongoose queries but struggling with some of the more complex stuff. Think this will help me see lots of the basic principles.

Thanks!!!

Schema as requested (relevant part only)...

```
var UserSchema   = new Schema({
    //....other fields  
    group: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    //....other fields
});

....

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

The 'd' in my question was just an example, it would actually be a 'group id' in my app.

**Solution thanks to chridam...**

```
var conditions = { group: groupId };
var update = { $pull: { group: groupId }};
var options = { multi: true };

User.update(conditions, update, options, callback);
function callback (err, numAffected) {
    // Do things here
}
```

Comment: Can you please include the schema in your question as well?

Comment: The Mongoose api is based on the underlying MongoDB query structure and query methods can have additional parameters for options and a callback function. You might want to look at the `findOneAndUpdate` method e.g `User.findOneAndUpdate({ groups: "d" },{ $pull: { groups: "d" } },{ multi: true }, function(){... } );` or [**Model.update**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html) method.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks very much, used the method from the second link you gave and updated with solution. Out of interest, would the first method you suggested work? Do findOneAndUpate and { multi: true } contradict each other?

Comment: It issues a mongodb `findAndModify` update command i.e. finds a single matching document (so `multi` in this case doesn't apply), updates it according to the update arg, passing any options, and returns the found document (if any) to the callback. The available options for this operation are `new`, `upsert` and `sort`.